# How can work the local name resolution?

Tags: networking, dns, arduino, mdns

I have an Arduino Yun connected to my LAN as client, and this is not my dns server. I can reach it using its hostname: http://arduino.local

**How can I reach it without a DNS record?**

I ask to Arduino community and they spoke about mDNS resolution, then I tryied to get those records using "Bonjour Browser" (https://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourbrowser) and I also tried a chrome extension. But I did not find any record from that IP address!

Then I tried with `nslookup` but it fails, because the DNS server doesn't have that record.
Then I tried with `nblookup`, because I know that there is another resolution made with NetBios. But it did not get any record.
I looked into hosts file and it was empty.

I tried to `ping arduino.local` and the resolution was good!

I cleared the DNS cache, pinged again arduino.local and then I printed the `ipconfig /displaydns` but i did not find any record about that name.

Comment: The `.local` TLD is officially reserved for mDNS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonjour Browser is actually a DNS-SD browser, not an mDNS browser. Do not confuse them:

- mDNS is the low-level protocol that runs on a LAN, and just like the regular DNS system, it allows publishing any record type – A/AAAA, TXT, SRV, and so on.
- DNS-SD (aka DNS Service Discovery) is *one specific way* of using mDNS – it's a higher-level feature that allows publishing "services" using SRV and PTR records.

So Bonjour Browser will *only* see records that were published according to the DNS-SD format, but local hostname resolution does not actually use this system. Resolving `arduino.local` to an IP address only uses the basic mDNS, so there's no service lookup, only a straightforward A/AAAA record query.

---

There's also the chance that your Windows system doesn't actually use mDNS, but its own LLMNR. Earlier Windows versions didn't have mDNS support at all (although it could come bundled with iTunes), and latest Windows 10 still needs it to be manually enabled.

In Windows 10, whenever you use names like `arduino` or `arduino.local`, the OS tries *all* local name resolution protocols: LLMNR, mDNS (if enabled), and NetBIOS (if SMBv1 is enabled). So you won't know how the name was found unless you actually [look at the packets received](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: At the end of my day, I can confirm that that information is coming from mDNS as suggested by Arduino community. @grawity you're right, I was confused by DNS-SD this si why I did not find what I was looking for. Thanks